# SQL table field named "Language" giving SQL error - delphi

Tags: sql, delphi, insert

I am building a application for school that displays and adds entries to tables in a neat and user friendly way. Whilst programming the "adding of new records" part, I came across this error

```
Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement
```

I tried fixing it by manually going through the list of fields I am entering and found that only one gave an error even though this field is exactly the same to all the other fields. If I purposefully spell the field wrong I get another error. My Code looks like this:

```
with dmInfo do
begin
  qryInfo.SQL.Clear;
  qryInfo.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO tblGymnast');
  qryInfo.SQL.Add('(GymnastID, Surname, Name, NickName, FamilyID, PosCode, CellNo, SAGFID, Photo, StartDate, BirthDate, Gender, Race, Category, IDNum, UpgrdTo, SchoolID, LevelID, TransID, DokterID, MedNum, MedID, Language)');

  qryInfo.SQL.Add(' VALUES(:GymnastID, :Surname, :Name, :NickName, :FamilyID, :PosCode, :CellNo, :SAGFID, :Photo, :StartDate, :BirthDate, :Gender, :Race, :Category, :IDNum, :UpgrdTo, :SchoolID, :LevelID, :TransID, :DokterID, :MedNum, :MedID, :Language)');

      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('GymnastID').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('Surname').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('Name').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('NickName').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('FamilyID').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('PosCode').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('CellNo').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('SAGFID').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('Photo').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('StartDate').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('BirthDate').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('Gender').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('Language').Value:= 'a'; //This gives the error
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('Race').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('Category').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('IDNum').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('UpgrdTo').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('SchoolID').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('LevelID').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('TransID').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('DokterID').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('MedNum').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('MedID').Value:= 'a';

  qryInfo.ExecSQL;
end;
```

Please help as I have been struggling with this for the whole day and haven't gotten anywhere.

Regards

Comment: which rdbms?  depending on that answer you may signify to the server that Language is a column name by wrapping it in [] brackets or double quotes or.... [Language] or "Language"  As far as your parameter it can be names whatever so you could change :Language to :Lang. also what is the actual error you are getting?

Comment: Sorry what does rdbms mean?

Comment: relational database management system.  e.g. mysql, oracle, microsoft sql-server etc.

Comment: The error I gave at the beginning of this post is the only error I am getting

Comment: I am using delphi sql with .mdb extension if that helps. Sorry noob here

Comment: the error you listed is generic to the entire sql statement so I wasn't sure  how have you identified that it is the language parameter assignment line, I was hoping there was more to it.

Comment: I commented out every parameter manually and then re-entered them until I got an error, which was when I added the language parameter

Comment: Using [Language] worked, but why did it give an error in the first place?

Comment: "why did it give an error in the first place"  Because without the [ ] the Sql engine's parser assumes that you are using a special SQL keyword (like 'SELECT', 'INSERT', etc) which, according to SQL's syntax, cannot validly appear where you are putting it.

Comment: Makes sense thanks

Comment: General tip: If a specific word doesn't work (for whatever reason), that word probably has special meaning of some kind - regardless of whether it's officially documented as a keyword. It's generally easier to pick a different word and move on (even when you do have a workaround) ***Side Note:*** _I recall a few years ago someone having trouble running a simple application called "language.exe". Windows didn't like the name. Solution: rename the program._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[] or "" signifys to the RDBMs that the word is a column name not a reserved keyword.  Language is a reserved keyword in SQL.

for good measure I also changed the parameter name to Lang because you identified the parameter assignment as teh issue location.

```
with dmInfo do
begin
  qryInfo.SQL.Clear;
  qryInfo.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO tblGymnast');
  qryInfo.SQL.Add('(GymnastID, Surname, Name, NickName, FamilyID, PosCode, CellNo, SAGFID, Photo, StartDate, BirthDate, Gender, Race, Category, IDNum, UpgrdTo, SchoolID, LevelID, TransID, DokterID, MedNum, MedID, [Language])');

  qryInfo.SQL.Add(' VALUES(:GymnastID, :Surname, :Name, :NickName, :FamilyID, :PosCode, :CellNo, :SAGFID, :Photo, :StartDate, :BirthDate, :Gender, :Race, :Category, :IDNum, :UpgrdTo, :SchoolID, :LevelID, :TransID, :DokterID, :MedNum, :MedID, :Lang)');

      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('GymnastID').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('Surname').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('Name').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('NickName').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('FamilyID').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('PosCode').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('CellNo').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('SAGFID').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('Photo').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('StartDate').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('BirthDate').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('Gender').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('Lang').Value:= 'a'; //This gives the error
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('Race').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('Category').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('IDNum').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('UpgrdTo').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('SchoolID').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('LevelID').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('TransID').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('DokterID').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('MedNum').Value:= 'a';
      qryInfo.Parameters.ParamByName('MedID').Value:= 'a';

  qryInfo.ExecSQL;
end;
```

Comment: Your comment about putting the Language inside [] worked, but why did only this one give an error?

Comment: Language is a reserved keyword in sql.  From, Select, ....other words are as well so you have to tell the SQL engine that you are referring to the word as a Column name not a reserved keyword this is done by adding the [] brackets or double quotes

Comment: Thanks I looked at different sources(Microsoft website) for reserved words, but after more investigation I see your point. Thanks for the speedy help, it is much appreciated.